# How do I plot a piechart for the following data frame

Tags: python, data-visualization

How do I plot a `piechart` for the following data frame?

ID                    Platform
1                      Viu

2                    Netflix

3            Netflix

4           Amazon Prime

5           Hotstar

I have a `dataframe` as shown above and I want to find out which was the most streamed platform and make a pie chart along with percentage. May I know how to do it?  I have around 400 rows. That is just a sample. Code in python pls.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? A good start in python could be [the basic pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html) of matplotlib.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes, i have tried -> df.groupby(['PLATFORM']).size() would need to plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write code for this to see how it works, that's not efficient.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = '''
ID Platform
1 Viu

2 Netflix

3 Netflix

4 Amazon Prime

5 Hotstar
'''

data = data.splitlines()

for i in data:
    if i == '':
        data.remove(i)

dic = {}
total = 0
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    dic[data[i][2:]] = int(data[i][0])
    total += int(data[i][0])

precent = []
for i in dic:
    precent.append((dic[i] / total) * 100)

labels = [i for i in dic]
sizes = precent
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0) 

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal') 

plt.show()
```